# How to make GET request with python-requests without downloading content

Tags: python-requests

If I make

```
r = requests.get('http://github.com', stream=True)
```

and see in tcpdump, the content of page downloaded just after requests.get. After r.content, no tcpdump transfer activity. The same with requests.Session(stream=True).

Comment: A GET request always downloads the content. The question is very unclear too.

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Are you trying to get make a get request and discard the output? Are you unable to see the output of get via requests?

Comment: So what are you trying to do? Did you perhaps want to make a HEAD request instead?

Comment: It is up to the *server* to start sending the body of a request. All `stream=True` does is postpone reading from the socket. The server won't wait for a TCP/IP 'please send now' signal.

Comment: This is not well documented, the .content reading from socket if all content in socket buffer, not recieving from server.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use `GET` if you don't want a response body to be sent by the server. Use a `HEAD` request instead if all you need is the header information.

All `stream=True` does is not read the response body from the socket. The server can still initiate sending that body, so the socket receive buffer will already have (some) of that body for Python to read.

Comment: Some sites blocks HEAD. The only way is GET.

Comment: Will stream=True make it any faster then or no?  It seems like it would, if your server is not reading the response content into its memory.

Comment: @kloddant: the server will still be sending more data over the socket, but your client at least won't be reading it.